# Solve a single cell in Sudoku

Tags: java, sudoku

I have a method for solving an entire Sudoku puzzle (checking for empty cells, and filling those cells with the current element in its corresponding position in the puzzle solution array) and it works great.

I am having a problem implementing an action for solving just one cell / square at a time. Any ideas how?

Here is the solver code:

```
public class SudokuSolver {

// set unchangeable number of rows to 9
private static final int ROWS = 9;
// set unchangeable number of columns to 9
private static final int COLUMNS = 9;
// the multidimensional array that will be the solution
private int[][] puzzleSolution;
// the 9x9 solution multidimensional array containing the correct puzzle values
public static int[][] solution = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];

/**
 * SudokuSolver constructor takes your incomplete puzzle and calls the solver method on it in order to get a
 * completed puzzle. The completed puzzle is stored in a solution multidimensional array.
 * @param puzzle the puzzle you want to solve.
 */
public SudokuSolver(int[][] puzzle) {
    // store puzzle solution into "puzzle" parameter
    puzzleSolution = puzzle;
    // solve the puzzle
    solvePuzzle(puzzleSolution, 0, 0);
} // end SudokuSolver

/**
 * next takes the current position in the puzzle array and moves it forward.
 * next calls upon the solvePuzzle method to continue checking values of the next array location. This is done so
 * if there is a non empty value in the array, we can skip to an empty one.
 * @param puzzle the array that is being moved forward
 * @param row the row position in the array
 * @param column the column position in the array
 */
public void next(int[][] puzzle, int row, int column) {
    // if we are still within the puzzle columns
    if (column < 8) {
        // solve puzzle by filling empty grid squares in columns
        solvePuzzle(puzzle, row, column + 1);
    } else {
        // otherwise, solve the puzzle by filling empty grid squares in rows
        solvePuzzle(puzzle, row + 1, 0);
    }
} // end next

/**
 * solvePuzzle loops through an incomplete sudoku puzzle in order to solve it.
 * It skips already entered 1 to 9 values using the next function, which then calls the updated function with
 * new row and column positioning. If a value doesn't already exist in its respective row, column, or block, solve
 * adds the value to the array and updates the positioning to check for a new value. At the end of the array, the
 * solution is sent to the "solution" array.
 * @param puzzle the incomplete sudoku puzzle being solved.
 * @param row the current row position of the array.
 * @param col the current column position of the array.
 */
public void solvePuzzle(int[][] puzzle, int row, int col) {
    // if the row value is above 8, then every empty value should be solved
    if (row > 8) {
        System.out.println("\nThe puzzle has been automatically solved!\nSOLUTION APPLIED:");
        // writing the rows
        for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
            // writing the columns
            for (int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++) {
                // array to hold the solution
                int[][] solutionArray;
                // places the solved array into the solution array
                solutionArray = puzzle;
                // print out the solution puzzle to console
                System.out.print(solutionArray[r][c] + " ");
            } // end writing columns
            // this empty println is needed to print the puzzle solution line by line in the console
            System.out.println();
        } // end writing rows
    } else {
        // as long as the value in the array is not zero, skip to next position
        if (puzzle[row][col] != 0) {
            // move to next position of row and column
            next(puzzle, row, col);
        } else {
            /* checks for duplicate values of 1 to 9 in rows, columns and 3x3 blocks, and if there are none, places
             the number in an empty location in the array  */
            for (int index = 1; index <= 9; index++) {
                /* checks that there are no duplicated numbers in the row, column or block, so that we can enter
                 the correct number into the right position in the array */
                if (SudokuChecks.findRowDuplicates(puzzle, row, index) &&
                    SudokuChecks.findColumnDuplicates(puzzle, col, index) &&
                    SudokuChecks.findBlockDuplicates(puzzle, row, col, index)) {
                        // set number at current position to index
                        puzzle[row][col] = index;
                        // move to the next position of row and column
                        next(puzzle, row, col);
                }
            }
            //puzzle[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
} // end solvePuzzle

/**
 * getSolution is a getter method that will get the values of a solved sudoku.
 * @return will return the correct solution to a solved puzzle
 */

public static int[][] getSolution() {
    // return the solution
    return SudokuSolver.solution;
} // end getSolution

} // end class SudokuSolver
```

What I would like is some sort of button that when clicked, fills a cell with the correct value, and if it is clicked again, fill the next cell, and so on. But writing the method for one cell at a time solving is more tedious than expected. Any ideas guys? Thanks much in advance!

EDIT: I should add, the puzzle solution is always printed to the console, and when "solve" is clicked, the solution is written into a 9x9 GUI grid of JTextField boxes. If a square has a value in it, it is obviously skipped. If a square is empty, it is filled with the number that is in its exact position in the console, thereby solving the puzzle.

Comment: Solve the entire Sudoku and each time the user clicks, make the cell appear from the solved one. Why is this a problem? Otherwise, you would have to implement a lot of solving methods to be 100% sure the cell solved is a possibility for the entire grid.

Comment: You cannot solve one cell separetly, there would be a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: A quick hack - store current table, solve it, then copy number from one random sell from solved table which is empty in stored table. But i'd rather rework solution - instead on checking constraints every time, i'd check them only when table changes and store results in table in form of bitmask. Then getting a one or more iteration of automatic solver is trivial.

Comment: Was this exact same question not answered only a couple of days ago?